# How to return two table values using join query

Tags: php, php-5.6

Here i am using JOIN query, it will working super, after merging two table value I return one table only, I don't know how return both tables values. From this code **task** tables value is returned, task_employee table value I can't return, I don't know what will do??

```php
$dapartment = $_POST['department'];
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM task_employee te, task t WHERE te.emp_designation='$dapartment' AND te.emp_id = t.t_assign_to");
$data = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)){
    $data[] = $r;
}  
$count = sizeof($data);
if($count > 0){ 
    $return=array('status'=>'success','count'=>sizeof($data),'data'=>$data);
    echo json_encode($return);
}else{
    $return=array('status'=>'not-found','count'=>sizeof($data),'data'=>$data);
    echo json_encode($return);
}
```

Comment: You **don't** use JOIN. Take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard way of an inner join is:

```
SELECT * FROM task_employee te JOIN task t ON te.emp_id = t.t_assign_to WHERE te.emp_designation='$dapartment'
```